# Bot Framework Directline Send Notification C#

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I have build a bot using bot framework and integrated into my website through directline. I have also started with creating a admin portal, where admin can have a look at bot analytics.

The requirement i currently have is the admin should be able to find all the users who are currently have chat with the send and push a notification to all those users if needed , if any body has already implemented such scenario please guide me in a proper direction

Thanks.

Comment: This question is not up to par with Stack Overflow Guidelines.   But to answer your question, take a look at `Signalr`

Comment: `send and push a notification to all those users if needed` Hi @saravan13, do you want to send notification(s)/message(s) to specific users via bot? Or just want to implement real-time web notification functionality to push notification to specific connected users?

Answer (score 1):

**Proactive Messages** is the terminology for 'push notifications' within the Bot Framework space.  Some documentation can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-proactive-messages?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

Conceptually, the bot developer persists a **ConversationReference** somewhere and that is later used to send a **Proactive Message**

Save conversationReference somewhere (memory cache, database, etc.):

```
var conversationReference = message.ToConversationReference();
```

Use that conversation reference to send the user a Proactive Message:

```
var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConversationReference>(conversationReference).GetPostToBotMessage(); 
    var client = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(message.ServiceUrl));

    // Create a scope that can be used to work with state from bot framework.
    using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, message))
    {
        var botData = scope.Resolve<IBotData>();
        await botData.LoadAsync(CancellationToken.None);

        // This is our dialog stack.
        var task = scope.Resolve<IDialogTask>();

        // Create the new dialog and add it to the stack.
        var dialog = new WhateverDialog();
        // interrupt the stack. This means that we're stopping whatever conversation that is currently happening with the user
        // Then adding this stack to run and once it's finished, we will be back to the original conversation
        task.Call(dialog.Void<object, IMessageActivity>(), null);

        await task.PollAsync(CancellationToken.None);

        // Flush the dialog stack back to its state store.
        await botData.FlushAsync(CancellationToken.None);        
    }
```